# Asus Memo Pad 10 (ME102A) - It is posible to hide navbar with Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2?

Tags: android, tablet, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm developing an app that needs to be fullscreen. I've tried some coding without any success which makes me wonder if it could be possible. If there is a way, how could I achieve this? If there is not, what could you suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target API. With 4.4 or later you might start with 
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html.

Otherwise try:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
...
```

Comment: Until onPause of the activity is triggered.